# Error when using String.search("sinh(2"): "Invalid regular expression"

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I have problem as below:

```
var test = $("#k_w").val().search("sinh("+parseFloat(sinh_array[i]));
```

The debugger shows an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /sinh(2/: Unterminated group`.

`sinh_array[i]` are numbers.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an opening parenthesis in your regex, but no closing parenthesis.

I think what you *really* want is this:

```
var test = $("#k_w").val().search("sinh\\("+parseFloat(sinh_array[i]) + "\\)");
```

I suspect you want to match the actual parens, and not create a group.

Answer (score 6):

The [`String.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) method converts the first argument to a Regular expression.

You are looking for the [`String.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method, which search for a string, without a conversion to a RegExp.

```
var test = $("#k_w").val().indexOf("sinh("+parseFloat(sinh_array[i]));
//                         ^^^^^^^ indexOf
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape parentheses in regexps; otherwise they begin a match group and thus have to be closed again.

```
var test = $("#k_w").val().search("sinh\\("+parseFloat(sinh_array[i]));
```

Comment: Within string literals, a double backslash is needed to escape special RegEx characters (such as the parenthesis).

Comment: Only for characters that are otherwise control chars.

Comment: `RegExp("sinh\(")` --> `SyntaxError: unterminated parenthetical`. It should be `sinh\\(`, as in the accepted answer.